# How to convert date time to unix command date

Tags: php, mysql, xml, sitemap

How do I convert **2014-10-10 04:13:24** to **2014-10-10T04:13:24+00:00** in php or mysql

The above mentioned date is for xml format in sitemaps

For reference check [Q: How do I compute lastmod date? (Sitemaps.org FAQ)](http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_computing_lastmod)

code which i have tried:

```
    echo "GIVEN DATE ".$timestamp = "2014-10-10 04:13:24";
echo "<br>";

$year = date('Y',strtotime($timestamp)).";
$month = date('m',strtotime($timestamp)).";
$day = date('d',strtotime($timestamp))."";
echo '<br>';
$hour = date('H',strtotime($timestamp))."";
$minutes = date('i',strtotime($timestamp))."";
$seconds = date('s',strtotime($timestamp))."<br>";


$gmktime= gmmktime($hour,$minutes,$seconds,$month,$day,$year)."<br>";

echo "output date".$isodate = date('c', $gmktime);
```

is the above out put conversion correct?

> ```
> **OUTPUT**
>
> GIVEN DATE : 2014-10-10 04:13:24
>
> output date : 2014-10-10T06:13:24+02:00
> ```

Comment: Where's the difference there?!

Comment: Both dates are the same. Have you forgotten something?

Comment: sorry please check now

Comment: Hint: If you've stored the date in a valid English date format, you can use `strtotime()` to get the Unix timestamp. That way you wouldn't need to call `date()` and `mkdate()`, which would make a difference in legibility and performance.

Comment: The reference of the time-format is [W3C Datetime encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). What you reference is how to get the last modification date from a file on unix in that format. But the format reference has more and is something different. See [Q: How do I specify time?](http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_specifying_time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP 5**:

```
<?php
// Set the default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');


// Get Unix timestamp for a date
// Reference: mktime(hour, minute, second, month, day, year)
$time = mktime(04, 13, 24, 10, 10, 2014);

// Alternatively (must be a valid English date format)
$time = strtotime('2014-10-10 04:13:24');


// ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)
$isodate = date('c', $time);

echo $isodate; // 2014-10-10T04:13:24+00:00


// RFC 2822 formatted date
$rfcdate = date('r', $time);

echo $rfcdate; // Fri, 10 Oct 2014 04:13:24 +0000
?>
```

References:

- [date()](http://php.net/date) / [gmdate()](http://php.net/gmdate)
- [mktime()](http://php.net/mktime) / [gmmktime()](http://php.net/gmmktime)
- [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) : [Supported Date and Time Formats](http://php.net/datetime.formats)
- [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) : [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/timezones)
- [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822)

Comment: You can use `mkdate` or `gmmkdate` for this. I added an example.

Comment: for the input 2014-10-10 04:13:24  i got this 2014-10-10T06:13:24+02:00 result. Is this correct?

Comment: Kind of. It's the correctly formatted date for your local time zone. If you want the GMT/UTC date, you have to use `gmdate()` instead of `date()`. I changed it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Your output *is correct* in the light of the Sitemaps.org spec. "`2014-10-10T06:13:24+02:00`" is the same date/time as "`2014-10-10T04:13:24+00:00`".

Learn more about the [W3C Datetime encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) which is used by Sitemaps.org.

Also, don't solve this with date functions, solve this with string function / operations: You change a single byte inside a string at a fixed position and then you append a string:

```
$timestamp = "2014-10-10 04:13:24";
$timestamp[10] = "T";
$timestamp .= "+00:00";

echo $timestamp, "\n"; // 2014-10-10T04:13:24+00:00
```

Or if you like to save some bytes in your file use "`Z`" instead of "`+00:00`" to denote the timezone:

```
$timestamp = "2014-10-10 04:13:24";
$timestamp[10] = "T";
$timestamp .= "Z";

echo $timestamp, "\n"; // 2014-10-10T04:13:24Z
```

Comment: not with the *date functions* because it's not necessary. the problem is not a date problem first-hand, but just a string operation. However, you should solve this with functions, by wrapping the example in a function and then use that function. Later on you can change handling the format easily, e.g. the said optimization with Z as the time zone designator.

Comment: Well, that would be true if the date is already UTC, but also the OP didn't say wether it's or not. +1 for the fact that if it were UTC, it's not an issue with time itself.

Comment: well, read the very first sentence of the question, it's pretty clear from it that it is the same timezone and that the timezone is UTC.

Answer (score 0):

**In PHP**

In PHP you use [strptime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) to parse the time and turn it into a structured array. Then pass the results of that into the [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function to get a UNIX timestamp.

**In MySQL**

Use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime_column) FROM table;
```

Comment: not working, it doesn't satisfy th format which i have mentioned in my question